# Как сделать так, чтобы Jackson игнорировал @JsonIgnore в некоторых случаях?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

У меня есть такое поле:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Organization organization;
```

Обычно мне не надо, чтобы оно отображалось в `json` когда я отдаю объект через `@RestController` `spring`'а. Но в некоторых случах я хотел бы, чтобы это поле все же отображалось. Возможно ли такое ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, вам подойдет аннотация @JsonView
Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)

Как альтернативный вариант, можно над классом вашей сущности повесить аннотацию @JsonFilter. Например:

```
@JsonFilter("contract")
public class SupplierContract
```

И в классе контроллера в методе:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getSerializableData(Object data) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String filter = "contract";
    String[] except = new String[]{"excluded", "fields"};
    SimpleFilterProvider provider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(filter, SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(except));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(objectMapper.writer(provider).writeValueAsString(data), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

В этом случае все поля, указанные в массиве `except` будут исключены из `json` для фильтра "contract"

Comment: Возникает вопрос. Как ведут себя аннотации `@JsonIgnore` и `@JsonView` вместе ?

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно использовать @JsonView отдельно. Прописать там только в каком случае выводить это поле